# Distributing out log equation

Tags: linear-algebra, logarithms

$$\log_{27}x = 1 - \log_{27}(x-0.4)$$

$$\log_{27}(x(x-0.4))=1$$
$$x=5.4,\, x=-5$$

I'm confused on the second line. How come it is not $\log_{27}(x+x-0.4)$?

Comment: I don't think this question deserves downvotes- it's a valid doubt that many people have.

Comment: It's not poorly worded or anything ... I don't see why it was downvoted either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\log(a)+\log(b)=\log(ab)$ where $\log(x)$ is the logarithm in any base.